# Draft Inducer Takes a Long Time to Start

Tags: hvac

When I turn the thermostat up I hear the draft inducer relay click, but the inducer motor doesn't start immediately like it used to. There's quite a lag time before I hear the draft inducer fan start up, but it will after a while. The motor is a shaded pole, so apparently no faulty capacitor to cause this. My concern is that since the thermostat has kicked the relay, current to a non-turning motor might cause a fire. Any ideas on the cause???

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How long are we talking here: seconds? minutes? hours?

Comment: I need to go back and do more observation, but I've left the shop after a few minutes without the draft inducer coming on, then returned within a few more minutes and it was working. Main concern is whether or not this symptom might potentially cause a fire. It always used to come on immediately after I turned up the thermostat and the relay kicked.

Comment: And the answer: ...... maybe? (Hopefully someone else will know more.)